# Spotify API returning {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant_type parameter is missing"}post request for refresh token(Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spotify

I am making a call to the spotify api for a refresh token however consitently get the method {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant_type parameter is missing"}
even though my code reads `grant_type: 'refresh_token'`and after reading the documentation am not sure as to the issue, any help would be appreciated !

This is my code so far

```
@response = HTTParty.post("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      body: {
        grant_type: 'refresh_token',
        refresh_token: ENV['REFRESH_TOKEN'],
        client_id: ENV['CLIENT_ID']
      }.to_json)
```

Answer (score 0):

The request to refresh a token must be done with authorisation:

```
@response = HTTParty.post("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization' => "Basic #{Base64.strict_encode64("#{ENV['CLIENT_ID']}:#{ENV['CLIENT_SECRET']}")}"
  },
  body: {
    grant_type: 'refresh_token',
    refresh_token: ENV['REFRESH_TOKEN'],
  }
)
```